# How to share image and text together at Delphi 10.3.3 in App for Android

Tags: android, delphi, share, delphi-10.3-rio

Delphi 10.3.3, Il trying to share a picture (bitmap) and a text together in one action in my Android App.
However, only the picture gets shared, while the text is absent in shared information.
How I can share **together** a picture and a text?

My code:

```
procedure TForm1.ShowShareSheetAction1BeforeExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowShareSheetAction1.Bitmap.Assign( my_Bitmap_to_share ); // here I assigned prepared TBitmap to share
  ShowShareSheetAction1.TextMessage := 'Here I assigned text to share';
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonShareClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowShareSheetAction1.Execute; // my my_Bitmap_to_share gets shared, but my text is not.... why???
end;
```

Comment: Where do you share to?

Comment: Sharing from my Android App to an external App as Android will propose to the user of my App, i.e. to Facebook, Telegram, Viber, WhatsApp, Email etc...

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Taking_and_Sharing_Pictures_and_Text_Using_Action_Lists They share a bitmap or text. Not both. You better ask @Remy Lebeau ;-).

Comment: @blackapps 
Thanks. I read this doc before many times ) However will wait maybe someone will advise how to share both - picture and text. Because in Android it is in general possible to share both in the same time.